# Update from Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.10

Tags: 10.10, upgrade

So I am running this really outdated version of ubuntu and i want do upgrade it without loosing data but cant. need help

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do it would be to make a backup of your files with a backup tool, (personally I like mintbackup), and then install ubuntu 12.10. Then once it is installed simply restore your old files and re-install your programs.  This method is not a true upgrade, but it is a lot faster, (the iso is compressed) and safer too.

As a side note you might want to make sure you like the unity interface, the old gnome one is no longer installed as an option. (Although you can install it later, I think.)

Hope this helps!

References:

- [How to upgrade, (For linuxmint, but a lot of it is still relevant)](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2)
- [Why you shouldn't skip over a release when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

P.S. If you could provide more details about why you cannot upgrade it would make it easier for people to answer. :)